# Lua development how to fix?

Tags: lua, crash

```
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/ Legacy crash hash: magazine-bravo-september
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/ Stack trace:
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/   RDR2_b1436.exe!sub_1402A844C (0x0)
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/   RDR2_b1436.exe!sub_14239B3AC (0x10b)
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/   RDR2_b1436.exe!sub_142409268 (0xd6)
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/   RDR2_b1436.exe!sub_140803CF8 (0x8e)
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/   RDR2_b1436.exe!sub_140F622C0 (0xd9)
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/   RDR2_b1436.exe!?Remove@fwMapDataStore@rage@@S?_PVstrLocalIndex@rage@@@Z (0x6f)
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/   RDR2_b1436.exe!sub_142B7B898 (0x1fc)
[     65047] [b1436_DumpServ]                13104/
```

How to fix ?

Comment: The game RDR2 has crashed.  But why do you think Lua is the culprit?

Comment: because why not

Comment: Because the crash clearly shows its not Lua related. Maybe indirectly caused by a script, but then you need to share the actual script. You should provide more information. What are you developing, how do you produce that error.

Comment: While passing through some points in the game and if there are many players next to it, the screen suddenly freezes and gives this error.